# Javascript prototype sorting function don't compare with all members

Tags: javascript

while I was cracking the leet code task I bumped into some unexpected behavior of the **.sort function**, so I couldn't finish my task until I implemented the insertion sorting function myself which helped me to sort an array of chars properly.

So the question:
why this function doesn't compare with all the array members?

```
function customSortString(order: string, s: string): string {
    const map={};
    for(let i=0;i<order.length;i++){
        map[order[i]]=i;
    }
    const newStr=[...s].sort((a,b)=>{
        if(map[a]===undefined || map[b]===undefined || a===b){
            return 0;
        }
        if(map[a]<map[b]){
            return -1;
        }
        return 1;
    })
    return newStr.join('');
    
};
```

if I call

```
customSortString("exv","xwvee")
```

it will return 'xweev', but expected "eexvw"

here is a description of the problem
[image]

If I put console.log into to sorting function

```
w x
v w
e v
e w
e v
e e
e v
```

So I can see, that "x" is not compared with "e". But if it did compare it would return 1 and would display "e" first then "x"

I hope I explained clearly, but ask questions if you didn't

Comment: `sort()` requires that the comparison function be transitive. So if it has already determined `e < w`, and `w < x`, it doesn't  need to compare `e` with `x`, it knows `e < x`.

Comment: The problem is that this isn't true if for any letters that aren't in the `order` string, because your function considers them to be equal to everything.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, it became more clear. I put return 0 there, because it doesn't matter where to put letter that is not in the order string. So as far as I understood, it's no way to do what I want, with this prototype function, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move unknown characters to the end, with a large value.

```js
function customSortString(order, s) {
    const map = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < order.length; i++) map[order[i]] = i + 1;
    return [...s]
        .sort((a, b) => (map[a] || Infinity) - (map[b] || Infinity))
        .join('');
};

console.log(customSortString("exv", "xwvee"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, more efficient answer,I use the map to record the frequency of every letters appearance,if a letter not in the map I will add it ,finally, I use repeat() to calculate all the letters in the map

```js
function sortStr(order, s) {
  console.time('test')
  const map = {};
  for (const i of order) {
    map[i] = 0
  }
  for (const i of s) {
    const num = map[i]
    map[i] = (num || 0) + 1
  }
  let res = '';
  for (const i in map) {
    res += i.repeat(map[i])
  }
  console.timeEnd('test')
  return res
}
const str = 'sdlfjsdifsdkfnweoosdfopdkmfndweoddfjosdfopdkmfndweoddfjosdfopdkmfndweoddfosdfopdkmfndweosdfopdkmfndweoddfjsdigklwjroddfjsdigklwjrjsdigklwjrsdigklwjrsdigklwjrdjlfgjsnfklgosdfopdkmfndweoddfjsdosdfopdkmfndweoddfjsdigklwjrigklwjroskfosdfopdkmfndweoddfjsdigklwjrgmcjbdlsmclgeosdfopdkmfndweoddfjsdigklwjrriciogiodfklsdgi'
console.log(sortStr('iskgupoeqvxzlafrdmn', str))
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works rather than just posting code? I guess it's depending on objects retaining insertion order. While this is true, it's a pretty confusing way to do it.

Comment: Yes, it's depending on objects retaining insertion order,so if the params contains number, it will not work correctly.I use the map  to record the frequency of  every letters appearance,if a letter not in the map I will add it ,finally, I use  repeat() to calculate all the letters in the map

Comment: The explanation should be in the answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to remove the characters that aren't in `order` before sorting. Then append them back to the result before returning.

When you do this, the comparison function doesn't have to check whether the character is in `map`.

```js
function customSortString(order, s) {
  const map = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
    map[order[i]] = i;
  }
  inMap = [];
  notInMap = [];
  [...s].forEach(c => {
    if (c in map) {
      inMap.push(c);
    } else {
      notInMap.push(c);
    }
  });
  inMap.sort((a, b) => map[a] - map[b]);
  return inMap.concat(notInMap).join('');
};

console.log(customSortString("exv", "xwvee"));
```